# Passar valor digitado para outro método

Tags: java, mysql, query

Estou com uma dúvida ao passar um valor digitado. Estou postando aqui porque fiquei a tarde inteira de ontem e não encontrei nada.

Na 1ª classe:

```
public class CompararLogin {

private String nome;
public String cpf;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public String solicitarCpfLogin() {
    System.out.print("Cpf: ");
    cpf = scan.nextLine();
    return cpf;
}

public String solicitarNome() {
    System.out.print("Nome: ");
    nome = scan.nextLine();
    return nome;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

}
```

Na 2ª Classe:

```
public class SocioDAO {

public void fazerLogin() throws SQLException, NomeUsuarioNaoInformadoExecption, CpfUsuarioNaoInformadoException, TelefoneUsuarioNaoInformadoException {

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.append("SELECT codigo, nome, cpf ");
    sql.append("FROM socio ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();

    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery();

    CompararLogin compararUsuarioExistente = new CompararLogin();

    String verificaNomeCadastrado = compararUsuarioExistente.solicitarNome();
    String verificaSenhaUsuario = compararUsuarioExistente.solicitarCpfLogin();

    boolean achou = false;
        while (rs.next()) {

            String nome = rs.getString("nome");
            String cpf = rs.getString("cpf");
            int codigo = rs.getInt("codigo");


            if (verificaNomeCadastrado.equals(nome) && verificaSenhaUsuario.equals(cpf)){
                System.out.println("Login Efetuado Com Sucesso!!! ");
                achou = true;
        SolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentesExceptions contarSolicitacoesEmprestimo = new SolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentesExceptions();
                contarSolicitacoesEmprestimo.Contar(cpf);
                System.err.println("SEU CÓDIGO P/ CADASTRO DOS DVD'S É: " + codigo);
                MenuChamarCadastroDvdEEmprestimo mostrarOpcao = new MenuChamarCadastroDvdEEmprestimo();
                mostrarOpcao.escolherOpcaoDvdEmprestimo();

            }

                }  if (achou == false) {
                    System.out.println("Usuário não Cadastrado!!!");
                    TratadorDeIniciarAplicacao voltando = new TratadorDeIniciarAplicacao();
                    voltando.main(null);
                }
       }
}
```

Na 3ª Classe: Esse método faz uma contagem de solicitações de empréstimo ou seja, o cara esta afim de alugar um DVD e fica em uma lista de espera, que eu pretendo passar esse valor quando o Login for efetuado com sucesso.

```
public class SolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentesExceptions extends CompararLogin {

public int contadorDeSolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentes(String cpf) throws SQLException, CpfUsuarioNaoInformadoException{

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT COUNT(*) ");
    sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
    sql.append("INNER JOIN socio ON (solicitacaoemprestimo.socio_codigo = socio.codigo) ");
    sql.append("WHERE socio.cpf = '11111111111' ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();
    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();
    int nCont = 0;

    while(resultado.next()){
        nCont = resultado.getInt("COUNT(*)");
    }

    return nCont;

}

public void Contar(String cpf) throws CpfUsuarioNaoInformadoException, SQLException, NomeUsuarioNaoInformadoExecption, TelefoneUsuarioNaoInformadoException{
    SolicitarEmprestimoDAO dao = new SolicitarEmprestimoDAO();

    System.out.println(contadorDeSolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentes(cpf));


}

}
```

Então pessoal, a minha ideia é a seguinte:
Quando eu digitar o CPF para fazer o Login eu gostaria que o meu método `contadorDeSolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentes` recebesse esse valor digitado do CPF. Então eu mostraria o resultado valor de pendências dentro do meu método `FazerLogin()`, que seria isso:

```
SolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentesExceptions contarSolicitacoesEmprestimo = new SolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentesExceptions();
                contarSolicitacoesEmprestimo.Contar(cpf);
```

Answer (score 3):

Você já está passando a String `cpf` quando você faz:

```
 contarSolicitacoesEmprestimo.Contar(cpf);
```

Agora, o problema era na hora que você montava seu sql.
Quando você faz, `sql.append("WHERE socio.cpf = '11111111111' ");` acaba por procurar apenas os CPFs com 11111111111.

Uma opção seria você montar da seguinte maneira, usando a String `cpf`:

```
sql.append("SELECT COUNT(*) ");
sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
sql.append("INNER JOIN socio ON (solicitacaoemprestimo.socio_codigo = socio.codigo) ");
sql.append("WHERE socio.cpf =" +cpf);
```

Comment: Embora a resposta possa funcioar corretamente, por favor, não incentive a criação de problemas de SQL Injection. O melhor é demonstrar como usar o `comando.setParameter(1, cpf)`.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver, vou postar aqui, quem sabe ajuda alguém.

Modifiquei essa classe:

```
public String pegarCpf(){
    cpf = getCpf();
    return cpf;
}

public int contadorDeSolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentes(String cpf) throws SQLException, CpfUsuarioNaoInformadoException{

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT COUNT(*) ");
    sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
    sql.append("INNER JOIN socio ON (solicitacaoemprestimo.socio_codigo = socio.codigo) ");
    sql.append("WHERE socio.cpf = ? ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();
    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());


    comando.setString(1, pegarCpf());

    ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

    int nCont = 0;

    while(resultado.next()){
        nCont = resultado.getInt("COUNT(*)");
    }

    return nCont;

}

public void Contar(String cpf) throws CpfUsuarioNaoInformadoException, SQLException, NomeUsuarioNaoInformadoExecption, TelefoneUsuarioNaoInformadoException{
    SolicitarEmprestimoDAO dao = new SolicitarEmprestimoDAO();

    System.out.println("Solicitações Pendentes: "+contadorDeSolicitacoesEmprestimosPendentes(cpf));


}

}
```

E na classe comparar Login modifiquei para static.

```
public class CompararLogin {

    private String nome;
    public static String cpf;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String solicitarCpfLogin() {
        System.out.print("Cpf: ");
        cpf = scan.nextLine();
        return cpf;
    }

    public String solicitarNome() {
        System.out.print("Nome: ");
        nome = scan.nextLine();
        return nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```